# How to write unit test case for device check

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I wrote below code to check device type

```
class Device {
    class func IS_IPHONE5_OR_BELOW() -> Bool{
        var isIphone5OrBelow = false
        if UIScreen.main.bounds.height <= 568 {
            isIphone5OrBelow = true
        }
        return isIphone5OrBelow
    }}
```

i write unit test for this

```
class TestDevice: XCTestCase {
    func testIsIphone5OrBelow(){
        let isIphone5 = UIScreen.main.bounds.height <= 568
        XCTAssertNotNil(Device.IS_IPHONE5_OR_BELOW())
        XCTAssertEqual(isIphone5, Device.IS_IPHONE5_OR_BELOW())
    }
}
```

in this How can i write true condition test

Answer (score 0):

i got solved by using below code

```
class Device {
    class func getDeviceHeight() -> CGFloat{
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    }
    class func IS_IPHONE5_OR_BELOW(deviceHeight: CGFloat = getDeviceHeight()) -> Bool{
        var isIphone5OrBelow = false
        if deviceHeight <= 568 {
            isIphone5OrBelow = true
        }
        return isIphone5OrBelow
    }
}
```

and adding below code for testing

```
func testIsIphone5OrBelow(){
        let isIphone5 = UIScreen.main.bounds.height <= 568
        XCTAssertNotNil(Device.IS_IPHONE5_OR_BELOW())
        XCTAssertEqual(isIphone5, Device.IS_IPHONE5_OR_BELOW())
        let testHeight:CGFloat = 500
        XCTAssertTrue(Device.IS_IPHONE5_OR_BELOW(deviceHeight: testHeight))
    }
```